# How to design layouts that will only rotate the outer layout not the inner layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I have two circle layouts(relative) inner and outer in Frame layout (parent), i need to rotate the outer circle by two finger gesture, but not the inner circle layout, how can i achieve this.[Like in below picture , outer circle will only rotate with their child circle but not the inner one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neDx5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I believe rotating outer layout by the amount you want and then the inner layout until it rotates 360 degrees will give you what you want.

> float degrees = 30.0f;
>
> outerLayout.setRotation(degrees);
> innerLayout.setRotation(360 - degrees);

Note that if you need to rotate the views again you should use the full degrees rotat on value. Meaning for 3 rotations 90 degrees, for 4120 etc.

Comment: thanks Spyros, it works , but rotation is very fast.can we rotate outer layout slow?

Comment: You will need to make an animator and use 
android:fromDegrees and 
android:toDegrees. Check this out and try something similar http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Comment: thanks Spyros, but i have rotate with finger gesture detection , clockwise and anti clock wise

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with RelativeLayout like this

```
<RelativeLayout>

   <LinearLayout>  //Your Outer Layout
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout>  //Your Inner Layout
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And perform operation on your Outer Layout. You can use any child view inside RelativeLayout according to your need. I just use LinearLayout for example.